# Kubernetes client library AuthenticationException

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-security

I've been using the Kubernetes .net client library version  for a while now to access the Kubernetes api from within a container. Today I updated from client library version 1.6.11 to 4.0.21 but this broke some part of the authentication of the client.

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
HttpRequestException. The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   (rest of the stack trace ommited)
```

With the inner exception:

```
AuthenticationException. The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I use the default inClusterConfiguration to create an instance of the Kubernetes Client:

```
KubernetesClientConfiguration config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig();
Kubernetes client = new Kubernetes(config);
```

After verifying that I could still talk with the API through curl using the token associated with the pod's service account stored in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/`.

I'm not that familiar with SSL but after some struggling I found a work-around by copying the ca.cert file from the serviceaccount directory to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and running `update-ca-certificates` but I do wonder what has changed that this action is now required.

Is there some way I can configure the client such that this is done automatically or resolved in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the client's Github I found [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/issues/585) that suggests a better work-around than I found.

```
KubernetesClientConfiguration config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig();
config.TcpKeepAlive = false; 

Kubernetes client = new Kubernetes(config);
```